# Getting String from Multi-Dimesnional

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array, methods

Could someone give me a hand, please? I have Multi-Dimensional Array that stores values of String.

```
private static JMenu[]                    Menu_Bars;
private static final String[]             Menu_names = {"File", "Edit", "View", "Search", "Info"};
private static final String[][]           Menu_Item_Data =
                                            {{"New File","Open   File", "Close", "Close ALl", "Save", "SaveAs...", "Print"},
                                             {"Undo Typing", "Redo", "Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "Delete", "Select All"}, 
                                             {"Text Color", "Font", "Text Size", "Background Color"},
                                             {"Search..."}, 
                                             {"Spaces count", "Words Count", "Sentences Count"}};
```

So... My Multi-Dimensional Array contains Arrays, so how could I get Strings that Array contains.

And there's a method there I stuck.

```
//menuComponent
private static void menuComponent(final JFrame frame) {

    bar = new JMenuBar();
    Menu_Bars = new JMenu[5];
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        Menu_Bars[i] = new JMenu(Menu_names[i]);
      }

    JMenuItem[] item = new JMenuItem[count = Menu_Item_Data[0][1].length()];
           for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {item[i] = new JMenuItem(Menu_Item_Data[0][0] /*How to pull Strings from Array in Argumments?*/ ); Menu_Bars[0].add(item[i]); }
    JMenuItem[] item1 = new JMenuItem[count = Menu_Item_Data[0][2].length()];
           for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {item1[i] = new JMenuItem(Menu_Item_Data[0][1]); Menu_Bars[1].add(item1[i]); }
    JMenuItem[] item2 = new JMenuItem[count = Menu_Item_Data[0][3].length()];
           for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {item2[i] = new JMenuItem(Menu_Item_Data[0][2]); Menu_Bars[2].add(item2[i]); }
    JMenuItem[] item3 = new JMenuItem[count = Menu_Item_Data[0][4].length()];
           for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {item3[i] = new JMenuItem(Menu_Item_Data[0][3]); Menu_Bars[3].add(item3[i]); }
    JMenuItem[] item4 = new JMenuItem[count = Menu_Item_Data[0][5].length()];
           for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {item4[i] = new JMenuItem(Menu_Item_Data[0][4]); Menu_Bars[4].add(item4[i]); }

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        bar.add(Menu_Bars[i]);

    frame.setJMenuBar(bar);

}
```

Comment: Do you need all the Strings from your 2D array?

Comment: Yes, as you can see every String should go in specific place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested for loop.

```
final String[][] Menu_Item_Data = {
            { "New File", "Open   File", "Close", "Close ALl", "Save", "SaveAs...", "Print" },
            { "Undo Typing", "Redo", "Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "Delete", "Select All" },
            { "Text Color", "Font", "Text Size", "Background Color" }, { "Search..." },
            { "Spaces count", "Words Count", "Sentences Count" } };

for(int i = 0; i < Menu_Item_Data.length; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < Menu_Item_Data[i].length; ++j)
            {
                System.out.println("["+ i +"][" + j +"] " + Menu_Item_Data[i][j]);
            }
        }
Output:
[0][0] New File
[0][1] Open   File
[0][2] Close
[0][3] Close ALl
[0][4] Save
[0][5] SaveAs...
[0][6] Print
[1][0] Undo Typing
[1][1] Redo
[1][2] Cut
[1][3] Copy
[1][4] Paste
[1][5] Delete
[1][6] Select All
[2][0] Text Color
[2][1] Font
[2][2] Text Size
[2][3] Background Color
[3][0] Search...
[4][0] Spaces count
[4][1] Words Count
[4][2] Sentences Count
```

Comment: You just made my day!, Thank you,  really helpfully answer and solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Loop:

```
List<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String[] arr1 : arr2) {
    for (String s : arr1) {
        allStrings.add(s);
    }
}
```

Java 8 solution:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(Menu_Item_Data)
              .flatMap(arr1 -> Arrays.stream(arr1))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Interesting way to solve this problem, thank you for your answer. :) I'II try it to.